# I can't get value of a property in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am coding in spring-boot. I tried to get the value of properties.properties in other packages without success. For example in the classe ClassUtils.java, the value of testValue is always null

This is my project

[image]

This is my code:

```
package com.plugins.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.plugins.domain.ClassUtils;

@RestController
public class SearchContactController {
    @Value("${environnement.test}")
    String testValue;

    @Value("${environnement.url}")
    String urlValue;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String pingRequest() {
        System.out.println("value ===> " + testValue + " /// " + urlValue);

        return "test !" + ClassUtils.getTestValue(); 
    }

}
```

This is my second class, where I can't get the value of testValue variable:

```
package com.plugins.domain;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ClassUtils {

    @Value("${environnement.test}")
    static String testValue;


    public static String getTestValue(){
        return "The return "+testValue;    
    }
}
```

This is my springApp.java

```
package com.plugins;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootVideApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootVideApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither class is an `@ConfigurationProperties`, and so neither will get the "relaxed binding" that you're probably looking for. Create a separate `@ConfigurationProperties` class to hold the information and inject it.

Comment: BTW, you have repeatedly mistyped `environment` in property names. Not that it's a technical problem but wanted to point out to rule that out as the cause.

Answer (score 2):

**Enable @ComponentScan({"com.plugins"}) , in Application**

To access the properties defined in **application.properties**

```
myapp.url="xxxxxx"
```

in your class

```
@Value("${myapp.url}")
private   String testValue;
```

but this cannot be a static variable, if it is a static variable you do some hack like this, by defining setter method

private   static String testValue;

```
@Value("${myapp.url}")
public void testValue(String value) {
            testValue = value;
}
```

Comment: I try your solution without success I stil get the null value in the other class 'ClassUtils.java"

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by addin @Autowired in the class which use the method of the other class this is a snippet

```
 // Class: SearchContactController.java  
@Autowired
    ClassUtils cd;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
    public String pingRequest() {
        return "Ping OK !" + cd.getTestValue();
    }
```